# Listen to values of a Search Bar over time with Swift Concurrency and Observation Framework iOS 17

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, combine, swift-concurrency

I have a view model that holds the `searchText` variable that is used in a view as a Binding for a `textField`.

```swift
@Observable
final class SearchableViewModel {
    var searchText: String = ""
    
    func listenToSearchQuery() async {
        for await searchQuery in searchText.async {
            print(searchQuery)
        }
    }
}

struct SearchableView: View {
    @State private var vm = SearchableViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("text")
                    Text("text")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .searchable(text: $vm.searchText, prompt: Text("Search text..."))
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .task {
                await vm.listenToSearchQuery()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that prior iOS 17 we had `@Published` and I could take the values from that String and use swift concurrency to listen to changes. Like this:

```swift
final class SearchableViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    
    func listenToSearchQuery() async {
        for await searchQuery in $searchText.values {
            print(searchQuery)
        }
    }
}


struct SearchableView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = SearchableViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("text")
                    Text("text")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .searchable(text: $vm.searchText, prompt: Text("Search text..."))
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .task {
                await vm.listenToSearchQuery()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even with this solution when I change one letter in the search query I get 3 printed lines and I do not know why but at least it works observing changes compared to Observation framework.

How can I do that in iOS 17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few observations:

- The [`async`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Lazy.md) method “converts a non-asynchronous sequence into an asynchronous one.” A `String` is a sequence of `Character` elements. Thus, if a `String` contained the text “test”, the `async` function would return an asynchronous sequence of the characters “t”, “e”, “s”, and “t”. It is not for observing changes in a `String` over time, but rather for asynchronously iterating through its `Element` values (i.e., `Character`), which is not what we wanted here.
- Instead, to observing changes of values over time with [Observation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation/) framework, there are two basic approaches that leap to mind:

  - We might use [`withObservationTracking`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation/withobservationtracking(_:onchange:)) from within the view model. See [SE-0395 – Observation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0395-observability.md) for discussion/example re `withObservationTracking`.

    Warning: There are some weird idiosyncracies with this API. This does not really “track” anything. It only observes the first change. You have to call it recursively to observe all changes.

    Also, it has a very non-conventional way of identifying what property is to be observed, so please refer to SE-0395’s [discussion](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0395-observability.md#withobservationtracking_onchange) carefully. E.g., you must simply refer to the property in the first closure (e.g., they literally suggest you just `print` the property). I hope they adopt a more idiomatic pattern in the future rather than relying on some side-effect of a `print` statement. Lol.
  - Or, we could use the traditional [`onChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-4psgg) view modifier:

    ```swift
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            …
            .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchText, prompt: Text("Search text..."))
            .onChange(of: viewModel.searchText) { _, _ in
                viewModel.search()
            }
        }
    ```
- Regarding the duplicate searches, I would advise deduplicating it programmatically, e.g.:

  - create a property for the “previous search string”;
  - create a local variable containing the new/current search string, and trim whitespace from it;
  - compare this local variable against the previous search string;
  - if different, do the search and save this local search string as the “previous search string”.

  Even when dealing with asynchronous sequences or Combine, we would do some sanitization like this, to avoid redundant searches. We would also frequently debounce to avoid too many soon-to-be-redundant searches, and you might want to do something like that here, too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How about AsyncAlgorithms? I noticed that there is a debounce but wasn’t able to find an actual example of debounce on a search string in a view model ?

Comment: That `debounce` is for `AsyncSequence`. You could create one (e.g., `AsyncStream`), but probably easier to just debounce yourself.

Comment: @Rob so seems like they've taken away the debounce option we used to have with combine if we are using the new observation? now we have to implement our own...

Comment: @Yosi199 – Debounce has not been removed. Still present in Combine as well as (via [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/)) for Swift concurrency asynchronous sequences.